# Meaning of "And you shall serve your brother" specifically for Esav and Yaakov

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, parashat-toldot

Unlike [another question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/118502/and-the-older-shall-serve-the-younger) that asks about the vague prophecy Rivkah was given about her twins, I ask specifically about Itzhak's statement to Esav:

> ... וְאֶת־אָחִיךָ תַּעֲבֹד ...׃ - And you shall serve your brother; [Genesis.27.40](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Genesis.27.40?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi&with=Ramban&lang2=en)

As I can see, most commentators skip this part of Isaac's prophecy. Unlike the other question, this verse has a proper grammatical form "את אחיך" similar to "אֶת ה' אֱלֹהֶיךָ תִּירָא **אֹתוֹ תַעֲבֹד**", meaning serving and worshipping, this verse states clearly that Esav should subserve to Yaakov.

Was it really a blessing or a prophecy? If a blessing, what kind of blessing is that? If a prophecy, what does this mean for Esav and when was it fulfilled?

Comment: https://www.biu.ac.il/jh/parasha/vayshlah/reg2.html לפי המדרש יעקב קרא לעצמו 'א-ל',

Comment: @TheGRAPKE And therefore...

Comment: Further, one of the names of mashiach is Hashem. "Therefore" I do not know ( :-) ), but *halo davar hu*, as per your diyuk.

Comment: @TheGRAPKE Did you mean that it says that Esov will serve God?

Comment: No, I meant that Esav will serve Yaakov who is God's representative.

Comment: Maybe Antoninus in Avoda Zara 10b, he served Reb Yehuda hanassi like a servant.

Comment: "_Unlike the former, this has a proper grammatical form 'את אחיך' similar to 'אֶת ה' אֱלֹהֶיךָ תִּירָא אֹתוֹ תַעֲבֹד', meaning serving and worshipping_". What about "את איביך" ([Deuteronomy 28:48](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Deuteronomy.28.48?lang=bi&lang2=en))? Or, "את עגלון מלך מואב" ([Judges 3:14](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Judges.3.14?lang=bi&lang2=he))?

Comment: @TamirEvan Thank you I edited the question. I meant, unlike the other question that refers to a different, less exact verse.

Comment: @AlBerko One of us seems to be misunderstanding the other. I understand you (even with your edit) as saying that 'לעבוד את' carries the [added] meaning of 'to worship' in all cases, just like it does for 'אותו תעבד' that you quote. I brought 2 examples, where "[וְעָבַדְתָּ֣ אֶת](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Deuteronomy.28.48?lang=bi&lang2=en)"/"[וַיַּעַבְד֤וּ ... אֶת](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Judges.3.14?lang=bi&lang2=he)" is used, but the meaning of "you will worship"/"they worshiped" doesn't make sense in those contexts.

Comment: @TamirEvan I simply meant that the former question/verse "רב יעבד צעיר" is unclear regarding who must serve whom. THis verse states that Esau must serve Jacob

Comment: @AlBerko Well, if that's all you meant, then my answer would be: As a whole, it's a blessing. "_If a blessing, what kind of blessing is that_"? It's the kind of blessing that's left, when Yaakov was made  master over him, given all his brothers for servants, and sustained with grain and wine ([v. 37](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Genesis.27.37?lang=bi&lang2=en)). The part you quote describes his situation, as a result of the blessing Yaakov got. The next part (והיה כאשר תריד ופרקת עלו מעל צוארך) was his actual blessing (that he had a chance of freeing himself from his servitude to Yaakov).

Answer (score 0):

Rav Hirsch says that as long as you (Eisav) insist on physical mastery of the world, then he will only come to lay it down at the feet of Yaakov. It is only when he understands the spiritual requirements of man will he understand what it means to be part of the family of Abraham.

> As long as you persist in ruling, looking on and using every material
> conquest only as the step for further conquests, for so long you are
> in reality working for your brother (only proving to the world and
> ultimately to yourself, the futility and lack of security which the
> power of the sword really acquires I.L.). As long as you are רב, for
> so long will רב יעבד צעיר, only כאשר תריד when you com down by your
> own free will, voluntarily acknowledge and submit yourself to the
> ideals of your brother, will you emancipate yourself and stand on an
> equal footing to your brother

Comment: Interesting, doesn't he think that Eisov (Romi) gave the world the best thinkers, philosophers, scientists and artists of their time? Also, what does "*he will only come to lay it down at the feet of Yaakov*" mean?

Comment: Also "*submit yourself to the ideals of your brother*", what ideas of ours exactly? Does he elaborate?

Comment: @AlBerko The gemarah brings the point that no matter how good or *advanced* the materialistic advances, they still only are worth while if they serve Hashem. The *ideals of your brother* are what were taught through the entire Torah. I quoted the exact citation on that pasuk. The remainder are found in the rest of Rav Hirsch's comments.

Comment: Where is the source for this?

Answer (score 0):

The full pasuk is important for context:

> וַיַּ֛עַן יִצְחָ֥ק אָבִ֖יו וַיֹּ֣אמֶר אֵלָ֑יו הִנֵּ֞ה מִשְׁמַנֵּ֤י
> הָאָ֙רֶץ֙ יִהְיֶ֣ה מֽוֹשָׁבֶ֔ךָ וּמִטַּ֥ל הַשָּׁמַ֖יִם מֵעָֽל׃
> וְעַל־חַרְבְּךָ֣ תִֽחְיֶ֔ה וְאֶת־אָחִ֖יךָ תַּעֲבֹ֑ד וְהָיָה֙
> כַּאֲשֶׁ֣ר תָּרִ֔יד וּפָרַקְתָּ֥ עֻלּ֖וֹ מֵעַ֥ל צַוָּארֶֽךָ׃
>
> And his father Isaac answered, saying to him, “See, your abode shall enjoy the fat of the earth and the dew of heaven above. Yet by your sword you shall live, **and you shall serve your brother; but when you grow restive, you shall break his yoke from your neck**.”

The Seforno says:

> **ופרקת עלו מעל צוארך**. כי אמנם תהיה מלומד מלחמה ומוכן לגדולות אבל אם
> בשעובדך תפנה אל עבודת האדמה ושאר המלאכות לא תהיה חפשי לעולם משעבוד
> אחיך או משעבוד זולתו:

> ...Because indeed you will be a scholar of war and ready for greatness, but if in your work (בשעובדך) you turn to the work of the land and the other crafts, you will never be free from the servitude of your brother or the servitude of others.

Comment: We all know to read interpreters, but I don't understand what it means. Can you elaborate please on your understanding of this interpretation?

Answer (score 0):

I saw in Ramdu (Rav Moshe Dovid Valle) it's literal. That Esav (Edom, Rome) literally wound up worshipping a Jew (JC).

Trying to find source.

Found source - fascinating piece, I included the whole section but the area with the green highlight the most relevant section.

[image: Rav Moshe Dovid Valle, Ohr olam, parsha toldot on that pasook, p.63 to 64]

[image: Rav Moshe Dovid Valle, Ohr olam, parsha toldot on that pasook, p.63 to 64]